# Запустить связку paperclip/s3 + задеплоить на хероку

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пробую запустить связку paperclip/s3 + задеплоить на хероку.

Делал все по данному [туториалу](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

В итоге 500 ошибка и ума не приложу в чем может быть беда.

paperclip config production & development

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
        :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
        :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
    }
user model
```

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
# This method associates the attribute ":avatar" with a file attachment
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
    thumb: '100x100>',
    square: '200x200#',
    medium: '300x300>'
  }

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar
```

логи papertrail

```
Jan 20 18:59:33 milker app/web.1: [paperclip] saving /users/avatars/000/000/010/original/0CE27BAE971DF6494F20441D62DFC0D1_1100_550.JP‌​EG 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2787ms 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError ( 
Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: Missing Credentials.
 Jan 20 18:59:34 milker app/web.1: Unable to find AWS credentials. You can configure your AWS credentials
```

Данная беда спать спокойно не дает.

в консоли не забыл прописать вот это

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key
```

Какие есть предположения?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Проблема решена

Comment: Обычная практика писать как была решена проблема, но чую вы просто забыли добавить конфиги s3 на хероке (судя по missing credentials)

Answer (score 1):

Забыл добавить решение. Прошу прощения.

Конфиги хероку были добавлены.

Все решилось вот такой моделью без использования Figaro.

Непонятно почему, но приходится делать вот так, а не как в официальном гайде.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :small => '60x60#', :large => '300x300#' }, :default_style => :large,
  :storage => :s3,
  :default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png',
  :path => "users/:id/avatar/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => "xxx",
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => "xxx",
    :secret_access_key => "xxx"
  }
```